# How to get specific icon in a container (like dll) in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can set in XAML the icon container:

```
<Image Source="Shell32.dll.ico" />
```

But how can I set in XAML the icon index in the container ? something like:

```
<Image Source="Shell32.dll,5" />
```

Or like:

```
<Image Source="Shell32.dll" Index="5" />
```

etc...

Comment: Your first version doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Because you probably don't have a file named "Shell32.dll.ico"... that was just a demonstration.

Comment: I tried copying Shell32.dll to my project and renaming it to Shell32.dll.ico.

Comment: But shell32.dll is not an icon file. That's exactly my question subject... anyway, I solved it via custom IValueConverter.

Comment: Could you share your solution with us in the form of an answer?

Comment: Check out this question on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/142731/which-dlls-included-in-windows-contain-icons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it goes: first the `IValueConverter`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class HabeasIcon : IValueConverter
{   
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr ExtractIcon(IntPtr hInst, string lpszExeFileName, int nIconIndex);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] fileName = ((string)parameter).Split('|');

        if (targetType != typeof(ImageSource))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        IntPtr hIcon = ExtractIcon(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, fileName[0], int.Parse(fileName[1]));

        ImageSource ret = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(hIcon, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return ret;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource iconExtractor}, ConverterParameter=c:\\Windows\\System32\\shell32.dll|72}"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351693/how-and-where-to-create-staticresource-key-for-a-converter-within-the-simple-xam