# How to apply if condition for WPF Project in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem`s. `TreeViewItem`s contain `Tag`s either `"type"`, `"class"`, `"subclass"`, or a `Guid` in the form `"0202-7252-4a4a..."`.

What I am currently doing is that I am displaying the `Tag` and `Header` of those `TreeViewItem`s on the screen with the following code.

(Please do not consider how I am creating the `TreeViewItem`s, it is not relevant for my case)

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"/>

<TextBlock>
    <Run text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"/>
    <Run text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

I don't want to write the `Tag` of a `TreeViewItem` whose tag is `Guid` because it doesn't seem pretty in the screen. I want to add an if condition to this code as follows:

```
if (TreeViewItem.Tag == "type" or "class" or "subclass")
    write tag and header to screen
else do nothing
```

OR

```
if (TreeViewItem.Tag is Guid) then do nothing
```

Comment: Please take a look at the CollectionViewSource class.  It will allow you to include a Filter on the elements within your hierarchical data structure, returning a Boolean value that reports whether the item should be shown.  Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888619/proper-way-to-use-collectionviewsource-in-viewmodel

Comment: hi you should visit this site, your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: Consider using a MultiBinding with a multi-value Converter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a converter that returns a `Visibility` for certain keywords. In XAML you can pass a list of keywords in XAML that will return `Visibility.Visible`, otherwise it will be `Visibility.Hidden`.

```
public class KeywordToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public List<string> Keywords { get; }

   public KeywordToVisibilityConverter()
   {
      Keywords = new List<string>();
   }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value is string keyword
         ? Keywords.Contains(keyword) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden
         : Visibility.Hidden;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary in scope, e.g. `TreeView.Resources`.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
   <local:KeywordToVisibilityConverter x:Key="KeywordToVisibilityConverter">
      <local:KeywordToVisibilityConverter.Keywords>
         <system:String>type</system:String>
         <system:String>class</system:String>
         <system:String>subclass</system:String>
      </local:KeywordToVisibilityConverter.Keywords>
   </local:KeywordToVisibilityConverter>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Do not forget to add the XML namespace for `system`.

- `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"` for .NET Core
- `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` for .NET Framework

Then, use the converter to set the visibility of the `TextBlock` depending on `Tag`.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=treeView, Converter={StaticResource KeywordToVisibilityConverter}}">
   <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

---

A converter for your second case is fairly easier, as it just checks the type (no namespace or list needed).

```
public class IsGuidToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value is Guid ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

As before, create an instance in XAML and use it to bind the `Visibility` of `TextBlock`.

---

As a note, if you wanted to bind the allowed keywords, too, the you would have to create a `IMultiValueConverter` used in a `MultiBinding` in XAML. If you want the `TextBlock` not only hidden, but removed leaving empty space, replace `Hidden` with `Collapsed`. Finally, to state the obvious: Be careful, the approaches are not equivalent. Depending on the *possible* `Tag` values they may lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Converter` for this type of issues.
With this methodology we can manipulate the `TreeViewItems`in such a way that "GUID" is not displayed in UI at the end.

## 1. Create a new Converter Class

During the generation of `TreeViewItems` it will hit this converter.

This class is implementing the `IValueConverter` interface. The `Convert` method will be used from XAML to convert the respectively bound object at runtime.

In the `Convert` Method you can add your specified if conditions you mentioned in your question.

Something like this should work:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Some condition to extract only "type", "class" or "subclass" from the tag property of TreeViewItem
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(Guid))
                return "";
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

## 2. Add the Converter to the respectively tag

First of all you need to add the namespace of the Converter Class to the XAML as a resource.

Read more about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351786/17604152

Adding converter as a resource:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainWindow"
....
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Converter"
>
......
......

    <Window.Resources>          
       <conv:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then you can

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Tag, Converter={conv:myConverter}}"/>
    <Run text="{Binding ElementName=treeView, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
</TextBlock>
```